# buildinstall не может скачать пакет

Tags: linux, centos, rhel

Когда я создавал респин CentOS, мне начинает жаловаться команда buildinstall, что не может скачать пакет:

> [root@localhost TEST]# /usr/lib/anaconda-runtime/buildinstall --version 6 --brand CentOS --product CentOS-Custom --release "CentOS-Custom 6" --final /root/TEST/Packages/ /root/TEST/
>       Running buildinstall...
>       /tmp/buildinstall.tree.4dkhbS ~/TEST
>       Could not download/verify pkg anaconda-13.21.117-1.el6.centos.x86_64: failure: anaconda-13.21.117-1.el6.centos.x86_64.rpm from anaconda-extrarepo-1: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

В интернете мало сведений об этой ошибке. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать.

Comment: запустите ту же самую команду, но добавьте перед ней `bash -v `, чтобы получить подробный лог выполняемых команд, и приложите вывод к тексту вопроса. там, наверно, будет много всего. можно оставить только строки после сообщения `Running buildinstall...`.

Answer (score 1):

> Could not download/verify pkg

ошибка говорит об одном из двух: либо программа *rpm*/*yum* не может скачать указанный далее файл (из какого-то репозитория), либо не может проверить его подпись.

вероятнее второе — не может проверить. это может происходить (как минимум) по двум причинам: файл «битый»/«левый», либо *rpm*/*yum* не обладает *gpg*-ключом, которым этот пакет подписан.

тут опять вероятнее второе.

> `anaconda-13.21.117-1.el6.centos.x86_64.rpm`

файл с таким названием отыскался в [репозитории `vault`](http://vault.centos.org/6.1/os/x86_64/Packages/). ключ, которым должен быть подписан данный файл в данном репозитории, это: http://vault.centos.org/6.1/os/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

скачать и добавить его в базу доверенных ключей можно, например, так:

```
$ sudo rpm --import http://vault.centos.org/6.1/os/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

Comment: Не получилось `error: http://vault.centos.org/6.1/os/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6: key 1 import failed.`

Comment: весьма странное поведение. вот [тут](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=4945) пишут, что это баг, который может происходить, если ключ уже импортирован. даже в [faq](https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/CentOS6#head-dcdb0c2fa3011ba53f6d24a139d003acc8f1d5a5) включили. типа, «это не баг, это фича». проверьте, на всякий случай, приведённой там командой. если выдаст две строки, то в первой должно быть `gpg-pubkey-c105b9de-4e0fd3a3`